# Why does my php web app doesn't get data from the database?

Tags: php, sql, database, azure, web

Ok, so I have a PHP web app in Azure but whenever I make a data request from the SQL database that I have connected to the app, it redirects me to an empty screen, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsIQd.jpg)

For example, I have a login screen, but whenever I insert the username and password and press login, a validation must be made by loading a username row stored in the database and comparing it with what the user entered. But nothing happens, it just redirects me to that empty screen. I have tested the same app locally and it work perfectly, but in Azure it doesn't work. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is there any code involved with this? You're describing things in frustratingly vague terms. Blank screens happen for a multitude of reasons. Without an error it's anyone's guess as to what's wrong. **Check error logs**.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I don't think that the problem has to do with the code, It works perfectly fine when I use the app locally with Wampserver64, Some context (and please bear with me as English is not my native language): I first created an empty PHP web app in Azure, then I created an SQL database (I didn't use the web app+SQL option, I created them separately), then I created a table on the database named "tbuser" with attributes username and password. Then I migrated the already programmed app that I used locally to the empty one I created in Azure.

Comment: if its not a code issue, your in the wrong place

Comment: Hmm, you say you use WAMP? Doesn't that use a MySQL server? Web App + SQL produces an Azure SQL Database, which is not a MySQL database :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PHP file and put the following content into it to check whether your application can connect to Azure SQL Database:

```
<?php

//PHP Data Objects(PDO) Sample Code
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:server = tcp:{your_servername_here}.database.windows.net,1433';
$user = '{your_usename_here}';
$password = '{your_password_here}';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to Azure SQL Database was made!";

?>
```

If your test is not successful, you will usually get a message describing exactly what went wrong. Common problems include:

- Incorrect server name for Azure SQL Database
- Invalid username/password
- Improper database name
- Access block at the database server

If you experience any errors, double check the connection information.

For more details, see [Use PHP to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php).